# Simulink - adding speed to car suspension model

Tags: matlab, model, simulink

I have made a basic "quarter-car" simulink model. It is a double mass system with two springs and two dampers. However I want to add speed of the car as a parameter to this model and I do not know how. Block "Step" is the bump size as an input from the road. [Screenshot of the model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lbdvdgrohstasi/simulink.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your quarter car model is in the vertical dimension only.  You wish to add the speed of the vehicle which will then add another dimension to your model.  This will require some thought.  How do you wish to model the input to the model once the horizontal dimension is developed?  I would recommend trying something simple like modifying the "Step" block(which I can't seem to find in your model) to create a larger disturbance at high speeds.  Then you can build from there, add profiles to describe road artifacts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added a wrong screenshot in the original post, but I have fixed that. Can you please take a look at it again? I have tried using ramp block along with saturation block, where the angle of the ramp would be the function of the speed, but then I got two impulses instead of one.. BTW I don't understand the downvotes..

Comment: The downvotes show that people feel you are not putting enough effort into the question before you ask.  Perhaps this is a case of not putting enough detail in the question.  For example, you have already tried a ramp, good job!  You're trying!  However, it's not obvious from the question that you've done that much work.  Post more of what you've already tried, plots of the output, etc, even the model, and I'll try and look at it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, here is the simpler version of the model(I have changed the other one a bit) https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5hbqrtc5621cog/st_model.slx, here is the model for creating bumps https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw5oueooycim3x5/road.m.

First I tried using ramp with saturation block, as shown on this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/359v0w24c1dtwk7/ramp.jpg

Then I tried using road.m to model bumps, it takes speed, lenght and height as an input. When I use different speeds in my model, it doesnt change the amplitude, only frequency, as shown here

Comment: Slow speed - https://www.dropbox.com/s/e312y2h6cbi63wb/normal.jpg
High speed - https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5gfj7hq79z5koy/fast.jpg

I am not a native speaker, so hopefully I have explained this well..